# Disable hibernation

Tags: 12.04, power-management, suspend, hibernate

As simple as it sounds I cannot disable hibernation. I have disabled any GUI option to disable hibernation but my acer aspire one has decided to start hibernating after an hour.

When I first installed 12.04 on this machine I followed a tutorial to get get the suspend function working and I may have fiddled with hibernation settings as well. The real clanger to all this is hibernation doesn't work on my machine so if it hibernates I must hard reboot (holding down the power ky for 5 seconds) to boot up my machine

I don;t know where to look for what might be starting the hibernation, and cannot find the tutorial I used in the first place.

Contents of Fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=72a8eda3-4259-4aed-a46e-32ca05f391c0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=0bcc2ac9-037f-43c3-81cb-53e0c3ad68e2 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
# Move /tmp to RAM
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid 0 0
```

Gparted screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVDRM.png

output of ls `-l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  5 15:45 0f9e0837-2ab4-429b-9c5e-81c156ae8197 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Sep  5 15:45 199020ec-61c3-4be3-aabf-0635a8b2994c -> ../../zram0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  5 16:09 28AA883BAA880810 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  5 16:08 509459C89459B168 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  5 16:09 588833E18833BC76 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  5 15:45 72a8eda3-4259-4aed-a46e-32ca05f391c0 -> ../../sda6
```

Comment: Can I help you with getting the hibernate work well instead?
Please give the output of the command `free`

Comment: Yes that would be IDEAL!   `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1931928    1750700     181228          0     116776     656232
-/+ buffers/cache:     977692     954236
Swap:      3288388       4552    3283836`

Comment: You have enough `swap`; so, that's not the issue. Please try `sudo pm-hibernate` and tell me how it behaves now.

Comment: It says `Not enough free swap`

Comment: Run `sudo swapoff -a`, then `sudo swapon -a` and retry `sudo pm-hibernate`

Comment: Ok that successfully shut down the system, it wasn't a hibernation because all the programs were closed as if I had cold booted. I there a way of searching for what might invoke the hibernate command?

Comment: Please give the output of `blkid` Or simple tell me whether you're using a swap partition or file?

Comment: You can't hibernate because your swap is encrypted, thus it can't be read at resume time.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem, Paul! [Yeah! Congratulations!]

You have enough swap, but it's not turned 'on' (or mounted). Please post the result of `blkid`

If you have a swap partition:

1. Run `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
2. Add the line at the end: 
   `UUID=[the-uuid-of-swap-from-blkid]   none    swap    sw  0   0`
3. Also follow these instructions:
   [SwapFAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

If you have a swapfile, go to: [Use swapfile instead of partition and hibernate](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042946)

UPDATE-1:

1. Open Gparted.
2. Right-click on /dev/sda5 and click on 'swapoff' or 'delete'.
3. Click on the 'tick' above the Disk-image.
4. Now, right-click, and click 'new'. Create a 'swap' partition. Repeat #3.
5. Click on 'information' on /dev/sda5.
6. Note the UUID. Replace the UUID in your fstab (4th line from bottom, the one after 'swap was...'.
7. Run `sudo -b gedit /etc/default/grub`
8. Find the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=..."
   and add to it "resume=UUID=" (leave the old text as it was)
9. `sudo update-grub`
10. `sudo update-initramfs -u`

For `blkid` issue:

1. `sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart`
2. `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks TomKat, but blkid doesn't return anything. I see even inside the /etc/fstab it says use this command, but mine doesn't return anything. To illustrate: `user@homepc1:~$ blkid
user@homepc1:~$ blkid
user@homepc1:~$ `

Comment: Please edit your Q and add: 1. contents of your fstab 2. A snapshot of 'Gparted'. If you don't have Gparted, `sudo apt-get install gparted` Also give output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Comment: @PaulK, Your `swap` partition seems to be dead. Check the Update-1.

Comment: Well turns out that wasn't my swap rather the unencrypted grub was there, After deleting this I couldn't boot so i 'upgraded' to 13.04 so I could atleast get my encrypted documents. Now however the system is terribly slow (4 year old netbook doesn't like 13.04 although 12.04.3 was totally usable.). I'm downgrading to lubuntu so I can atleast work again.

Comment: Hey! You could just boot using a LIVE CD/DVD/USB and run `sudo update-grub` & `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` It'd have restored the GRUB!